# Passing through subclass as parameter using this

Tags: c++, visual-c++, arguments, parameter-passing

I'm trying to send a class as a parameter to a constructor using `this` and I'm doing this in two different classes `CasinoDealer` and `Gambler`, so on the receiver end `StandAction` I have a constructor who is taking 2 arguments `performer` and `hand`.

Performer is the class, but I have the argument as a base class whom `CasinoDealer` and `Gambler` both are inheriting; `Player` base class.

I thought since the `Gambler` class or the `CasinoDealer` class were inheriting the `Player` base class, I could send the class using `this`, and the receiving end have `Player* performer` as the argument, and know which class who created the object, but apparently this doesn't work, so how would I do this?

I left out some includes, and unimportant functions like that to minimize code posted.

Gambler.cpp

```cpp
Action* Gambler::GetAction(int input) {
    Action* action = nullptr;
    switch (input) {
    case 1:
        action = new StandAction(this, new Hand());
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return action;
}
```

Player.h

```cpp
class Player {
public:
    virtual Action* DecideNextMove() = 0;
};
```

StandAction.h

```cpp
class StandAction : public Action {
public:
    StandAction(Player* performer, Hand hand);
    void Execute();
};
```

StandAction.cpp

```cpp
StandAction::StandAction(Player* performer, Hand hand) : Action(performer, hand) {

}
```

It's complaining about no instance of constructor is matching argument list. I thought if the class I sent inherited `Player` it would be fine to pass as an argument, and have `Player* performer` on the receiver end.

```cpp
C++ no instance of constructor matches the argument list
            argument types are: (Gambler *, Hand *)
```

Comment: Look at the other parameter and its argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the error is quite clear to me. `new Hand()` returns `Hand*`, not a `Hand` required by the `StandAction`constructor. So you probably want `new StandAction(this,Hand());`

Please don't use `new`, use `std::unique_ptr<T>` and return `std::unique_ptr<Action>` by value. It's good practice to only use raw pointers for a non-owning relationship unless you know what you are doing.

**EDIT:** Using `unique_ptr`:

```
std::unique_ptr<Action> Gambler::GetAction(int input) {
    std::unique_ptr<Action> action;
    switch (input) {
    case 1:
        action = std::make_unique<StandAction>(this, Hand());
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return action;
}
```

Since you are casting `StandAction*` to `Action*` in both cases, make sure that `Action::~Action()` is virtual.